# combine multiple similar function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I have data inside 10 mysql table and I want to display them as chart. I want to make function to display only one chart per click. So far I hard code every html tag and js function, the hard code is

```html
<p onclick="dOgan()">display ogan</p>
<p onclick="dKomering()">display komering</p>

<canvas id="ogan" width="200" height="120" style="display: block;" class="show"></canvas>
<canvas id="komering" width="200" height="120" style="display: block;" class="show"></canvas>

    var ctx = document.getElementById(`ogan`);
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [<?php while ($t = mysqli_fetch_array($time)) {
                            echo '"' . $t['time'] . '",';
                        } ?>],
            datasets: [{
                label: `ogan`,
                data: [<?php while ($v = mysqli_fetch_array($water_level)) {
                            echo '"' . $v['water_level'] . '",';
                        } ?>],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(35,137,218, 0.7)',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

var station = document.querySelectorAll("#komering, #ogan");
function dOgan() {
    for (var i = 0; i < station.length; i++) {
        station[i].style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('#ogan').style.display = "block";
    }
}

function dKomering() {
    for (var i = 0; i < station.length; i++) {
        station[i].style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('#komering').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

I'm using chartJS to make the chart. How can I make it without hardcoding?. I tried using loop, but nothing worked, I don't fully understand loop, also the php-javascript combination simply confused me. any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code where you added the values to the labels list, you add a comma at the end of each loop, even on the last iteration. This can cause an error because chartJS is expecting another value, but instead, you are ending the data list there. I would suggest having a different echo statement for the last loop where a comma is not appended at the end. This could fix your error. If nothing shows up, I have used chartJS and found that the values will update through a built-in function: `myChart.update();` should work. If nothing happens after all of this, check the console for any errors.